# How to run commands written in text file in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I just made a text file with the following commands to launch Xilinx Vivado software. How can I run this text file directly from the Terminal, so that I don't need to copy and paste all these commands in Terminal manually to run.

```
abc@alpha:source /Xilinx/Vivado/2021.1/settings64.sh
abc@alpha:source /Xilinx/Vitis/2021.1/settings64.sh
vivado
```

Comment: Research bash scripts.

Comment: How to make bash script

Comment: Yes it works. I just make a bash script and run it in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways around this in my books.
First you can run it with bash as follows:

```
bash /Xilinx/Vivado/2021.1/settings64.sh
bash /Xilinx/Vitis/2021.1/settings64.sh
```

Or you can add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of each script - then you can make that script executable with the `chmod` command.

```
chmod 770 /Xilinx/Vivado/2021.1/settings64.sh
chmod 770 /Xilinx/Vitis/2021.1/settings64.sh
```

Then you can execute the script directly in the directory it's in with

```
./settings64.sh
```

Or you can make a 3rd script that runs them 1 by one.
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: security wise 750 is better  ;-)